# Find a minimum of $f(x,y)$ without the isoperimetric inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $H=\{(x,y)\in R^2: y>0\}$, and let $f:H\to R$  be defined by $$f(x,y)=\frac{2+\sqrt{(1+x)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(1-x)^2+y^2}}{\sqrt y}.$$
Show that $f$ attains its minimum on $H$ at a unique point and find that point.

The numerator is the perimeter of the triangle with vertices $(\pm 1,0), (x,y)$. The denominator is the root of its area. I can use the isoperimetric inequality for triangles (and that the equality is achieved for regular triangles) to solve this. But could I solve this if I didn't know the inequality? Dealing with partial derivatives seems to be too cumbersome. Or is the purpose of this problem to prove the isoperimetric inequality? If so, how do I prove it (and that the equality is achieved for regular triangles)?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use that $$ a^2+b^2 \geq {1\over 2}(a+b)^2$$

---

Then :

$$\sqrt{(1+x)^2+y^2} \geq {1\over \sqrt{2}}(1+x+y)$$ and

$$\sqrt{(1-x)^2+y^2} \geq {1\over \sqrt{2}}(1-x+y)$$ so

$$f(x,y)\geq \frac{2+ \sqrt{2}(1+y)}{\sqrt y}\geq {2\sqrt{\sqrt{2}(2+\sqrt{2})y}\over \sqrt{y}} =2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}+2}$$ Last inequality is between AG and GM ($a+b\geq 2\sqrt{ab}$).

Comment: Is this a hint to prove the isoperimetric inequality or to solve the problem alternatively? (The question is to help me understand how to apply this.)

Comment: Second one.....probably.

Comment: For the last inequality (ignoring denominators), I get $\frac{4+2\sqrt 2(1+y)}{2}\ge 2\sqrt{2\sqrt 2 (1+y)}$. And how does this help to find the point at which the maximum is attained? Why is it unique?

Comment: No, write $$(2+\sqrt{2})+y\sqrt{2} \geq 2\sqrt{\sqrt{2}(2+\sqrt{2})y}$$

Comment: Equality is achieved iff $a=b$ so at $y=\sqrt{2}+1$

Comment: Sorry, how did you get $y=\sqrt 2 + 1$? Doesn't this contradict to the isoperimetric inequality? The equality in it occurs if the triangle is regular, which happens if $x=0, y=1$. In our case $a=1+x, b=y$ and $a=1-x,b=y$; this system gives $x=0,y=1$.

Comment: $$a= 2+\sqrt2 = y\sqrt{2}=b$$

Comment: Oh, I thought you was applying this for $a$ and $b$ from the original hint... And my previous comment is of course wrong. Thanks!

Comment: But still $y=\sqrt 2+1$ doesn't look right. The triangle is equilateral if $y=\sqrt 3$, as in the answer of @zwim below.

Answer (score 1):

$f(-x,y)=f(x,y)$ so $x=0$ is an axis of symmetry.

From the form of $f(x,y)$ you can see that it will increase if $|x|$ increases, so the minimum if it exists will be reached on the line $x=0$.

$f(0,y)=\dfrac{2+2\sqrt{1+y^2}}{\sqrt{y}}$

This is not to complicated to derivate $\dfrac{y^2-1-\sqrt{1+y^2}}{y\sqrt{y}\sqrt{1+y^2}}$

Annulation of denominator arises for $(y^2-1)^2=1+y^2\iff y^4=3y^2\implies y=\sqrt{3}$ on the domain $H$.

$f(0,\sqrt{3})=2\times 3^{\frac 34}\approx 4.559...$

---

@Angle

In your answer you get $2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}+2}\approx 4.394...$ which is less what I obtained, so one of us did wrong.

I understood you were obtaining $y=1+\sqrt{2}$ but $f(0,1+\sqrt{2})\approx 4.650...$, I'm confused about the values of $(x,y)$ for the minimum ?

Comment: $y=\sqrt 3$ looks correct because in this case the triangle is equilateral, and the isoperimetric inequality is actually an equality.